# What interface do DNS, DHCP, Sage and mail server use?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Network Engineering Stack Exchange post: [What interface do DNS, DHCP, Sage and Mail server use?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/44496/what-interface-do-dns-dhcp-sage-and-mail-server-use)

Comment: What is your question about that post?

Comment: The attached image is incorrect. Its default gateway is not the same network.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you question here is, but your original question is off-topic on Network Engineering. Please read the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) That explains that all "*education, certification, or homework*" questions are off-topic.